CONEXION DE DATOS CRYSTAL REPORTS DESDE VISUAL BASIC
necesito de su apoyo para saber si es posible extraer el nombre del servidor desde un archivo DB.ini para conectar a crystal
ejemplo:
Servidor pruebas de DB.ini: dbpruebas
Servidor producción DB.ini: dbProduccion
Cuentan con los mismos datos ServerName , DatabaseName ,  UserID , Password
loginfo = New CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfo
    loginfo.ServerName = "SERVERNAME"

    loginfo.DatabaseName = "DBNAME"

    loginfo.UserID = "USER"

    loginfo.Password = "PASS"

Solo quiero implementar que cuándo este en pruebas se conecte a dbpruebas y cuando este en producción se conecte a  dbProduccion sin necesidad de cambiar la conexión en el ODBC
